# Vote count doesn't update unless you refresh the question

Tags: bug, down-votes, android-app, up-votes

When you long hold the up vote/down vote box the Vote count box (it displays the amount of up votes and down votes) will pop up, but if you vote on the post and check it again the amount if votes aren't updated e.g.

[image: vote count]